# Strong parameters for nested attributes are ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I am trying to use string parameters to allow passing in nested attributes for a model and for whatever reason the `permit` method is ignoring anything that is nested. See below:

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_number, :address, update_only: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profession, update_only: true
end
```

Controller:

```
class Api::V1::Users::UsersController < Api::BaseController
  def update
    permitted = permitted_user_params
  end

  def permitted_user_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      phone_number_attributes: [:phone_number],
      address_attributes: [:street, :city, :province, :country, :postal_code],
      profession_attributes: [:company, :title, :designation]
    )
  end
end
```

If I pass in correctly formatted data permitted_user_params will not return any values other than `first_name, last_name, password and password_confirmation`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think you forget id of nested models: `phone_number_attributes: [:id, :phone_number],
      address_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :province, :country, :postal_code],
      profession_attributes: [:id, :company, :title, :designation]`

Comment: Including the `:id` for each doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you figured this one out yet? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: @MFrazier - See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. When you post to the endpoint your data needs to match the expected format on the rails side. For the example above you'd need to post your data like:

```
{
    profile: {
        first_name,
        last_name,
        password,
        password_confirmation,
        phone_number_attributes: {
            phone_number
        },
        address_attributes: {
            street,
            city,
            province,
            country,
            postal_code
        },
        profession_attributes: {
            company,
            title,
            designation
        }
    }
}
```

Rails explicitly looks for keys with the value `_attributes` on the end and if it can't find anything it just carries on and does not sanitize those attributes for you.